# Am I betraying myself doing the job I am doing?

Tags: career-switch, careers, depression

I am a web developer, fullstack, to be honest I prefer frontend, because more "creative", there is styles, design, integration.

So what I know about myself is that I like originality, creativity, art, I am a musician etc.

Doing my job actually it's opposite of what I am, but I've learnt since childhood that I can do more or less everything if it's obligatory, this is the main lesson at school, and in society in general. So today I am fullstack dev, average one, as I've always been average in everything (which is not good in our modern life), and this is why every job is kind of the same for me as soon as it's not what I want, and I am not 100% sure of what I want, so I keep doing what random world / or god put in my way.

After this philosophic introduction, my question is : are there many of us in this situation ? are we betraying ourselves by spending our precious time/life not doing what our deep soul wants us to do, and but because of all these years of society/school/local culture brainwashing we do not hear this voice deep?

Comment: Why has this been tagged [depression]?

Comment: I'm afraid that is not really a focused question where we can give good advice on navigating the workplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the japanese concept of:
Ikigai

Do something you are good at, what you love, what you are paid for, and the world needs.

Every job will contain parts you dislike, make sure there are enough parts you "love" that you can stomach those.
Maybe you have to change your environment/company. Being a developer myself, working at a company that "just" makes money and doesn't really care how feels very different from a company which does so in explicit unethical ways (whatever you consider unethical, there are certain things I would never work for, like weapons manufacturers). And it feels very different on working on something that you think improves the world. My current project is on the one hand a very normal project: some feature, some testing, some wrestling with deployment, write documentation no one has written before, argue with unrealistic expectations, etc...
But I can regularly remind I do this for a very good goal!

I sometimes dream about becoming a writer instead of a developer. But if I am being honest, this is more an escapist fantasy than a real desire of mine. I am good at developing, I am good at architecture, and I learned how to clearly communicate technical aspects. So I am right at home in Softwaredevelopmentprojects. I just try to work on things I can actually believe in.

So I recommend you find out you find out what you want, and figure a way you get payed for it. If that means working a true frontendjob instead of fullstack: There will be a job for you. Maybe you have to just find a product you can believe in. Maybe you can switch to an adjacent field, like design. (It pays less than development, and you will likely find you will have less freedom than you imagined before starting)

Comment: There are also plenty of people who do the thing they love outside of "work", the less exciting job providing the financial means to write/act/paint/climb/volunteer/whatever

Comment: definitely! I work my 40h a week (on average) and do follow other interests in my spare time. I also volunteer. I still prefer my 40h contribute to something I think will do good. Some people can stomach jobs they find boring/stupid and live for their family/free time. A very common model in society. The way OP phrased his post, I don't believe that model works for him though.

Answer (score 2):

Most people work to pay the bills and have money to enjoy other things outside work. In terms of enjoyment, for the majority the job itself doesn't matter as much as the people and conditions at the workplace.

> because of all these years of society/school/local culture brainwashing

This is the normal human condition since forever (2 million years at least). We hunted and gathered for food to sustain us, not everyone enjoys putting their lives on the line for meat and grubbing around in the dirt for roots.

Nowadays there is more opportunity to get work you enjoy for it's own sake, but it's neither necessary nor usual.

I've worked several industries and positions, I've enjoyed each one that had a good crew of people and decent conditions.